# App crashes at [UIWebView webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

I am implementing a simple in-app browser. In my home view (`UITableViewController`), I have something like:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                webViewController.stringURL = @"http://www.google.com";
                break;
            case 1:
                webViewController.stringURL = @"http://www.bing.com";
                break;
            default:
                webViewController.stringURL = @"http://stackoverflow.com"; 
                break;
        }

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
        [webViewController release];
    }
```

The app *crashed* after I repetitively navigated back and forth between my home view and `webViewController`a few times.

Inside `WebViewController` class, I have nothing but a `[UIWebView *webView]` and a `[UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator]`. Both are with attributes `nonatomic, retain`. Here is the implementation.

```
        #import "WebViewController.h"
        @implementation WebViewController
        @synthesize webView, activityIndicator, stringURL;

        - (void)dealloc
        {
            [self.webView release];
            self.webView.delegate = nil;
            [self.activityIndicator release]; 
            [super dealloc];
        }

        -(void)loadView {
            UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
            self.view = contentView;    

            CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
            webFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
            self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
            self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
            self.webView.delegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview: self.webView];
            [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.stringURL]]];

            self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
            self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
            [self.view addSubview: self.activityIndicator];
        }

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {   
            [super viewDidLoad];
            [self loadView];
        }

        - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
        {
            // starting the load, show the activity indicator in the status bar
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        }

        - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
        {
            // finished loading, hide the activity indicator in the status bar
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }

        @end
```

I just ran my app in Instruments using the *Zombies template*, which shows `-[UIWebView webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:]` is the Zombie call. But I still can’t figure out what is actually the problem.

(Please download [trace](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2320244/crash.trace.zip) if needed)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Update]:

1. As @7KV7 and @David pointed out, there is an obvious bug in my `dealloc` function. I should call `self.webView.delegate=nil;` first before I release `self.webView`. Sorry about that. Unfortunately, after I fix it, the app still crashes in the same way.
2. If I delete  `[webViewController release];`  from the first code block, the crash actually is gone. But obviously, there will be memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove that call to `loadView` in `viewDidLoad`. The framework will the call the method when it doesn't find a view provided in XIB file. Second, your `loadView` is filled with memory leaks. You are allocating, initializing and retaining an object every time the method is called. So you are taking ownership twice and releasing it only once in the dealloc.

The objects are not being properly deallocated. You should do something like alloc-init-autorelease to solve this. Next thing is the that every time the controller gets loaded, because of your call to `loadView`, you end up creating two web view objects and two requests. You lose reference to one of them as you reassign. Herein, lies the problem mentioned in the title. You aren't able to reset the delegate of a web view object that has your controller as a delegate. Imagine a request being completed soon after you leave. Here the message will go to a zombie object. This is a pretty good example for why you need to `nil` out your delegates.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)dealloc
{
self.webView.delegate = nil;
[self.webView release];
[self.activityIndicator release]; 
[super dealloc];
}
```

Try this `dealloc`. You were releasing the `webview` and then setting the `delegate` as `nil`. You should first set the `delegate` as `nil` and then `release` it. Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: @7KV7, thanks, this is probably one flaw in the program. But unfortunately, it does not fix the crash. Still Zombie messaged at the same place.

Comment: Can you try again after cleaning the build. I could find only this issue in your code

Comment: @7KV7, just tried. Still got the crash. The crash information in the console is `-[WebViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc4735c0`. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Obviously you are trying to access something that is already released. Can you check your entire code again to see if u r releasing some object anywhere else

Comment: The code is pretty much posted. Note, if I delete `[webViewController release];` in the first code block, there will be no crash. But obviously, the memory usage will climb up. :(

Comment: Its just a try. Can you remove the line `[self.activityIndicator release];` in dealloc and try.

Comment: @Zeiga: Thank you. Even @David deserves one

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that you are going back while the page is still loading so the controller gets deallocated and then the webview finishes loading.
Try calling [webView stopLoading] in your viewDidUnload method to make sure this isn't happening.

Comment: I think this is in the right direction. But simply appending [webView stopLoading] did not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but this is definitely wrong:

```
[self.webView release];
self.webView.delegate = nil;
```

You cannot (safely) refer to `self.webView` after you release it!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @David. But it seems not the key to fix the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing webViewController,add its view to self.view .
Dont call [self loadView]; in viewDidLoad.

Comment: If I do not call `[self loadView]`, where should my initialization of the `webView` and `activityIndicator` go?

Comment: @Zeiga it will be called automatically. @impossiblepriya view controllers are there to reduce the pain in manual management of views. Why would you suggest we dump convenience?